# php - Displaying more than one image from a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to display images (and other data connected to them, e.g. titles) in a table. The filenames of the images are stored in my database as `imgname`, but the problem is that there is only one image that is being displayed.
Here is the code I use. What should I change?

```
mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_img = "SELECT imgname FROM img ORDER BY imgname";
$img = mysql_query($query_img, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_img = mysql_fetch_assoc($img);
$totalRows_img = mysql_num_rows($img);
```

Table

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="images/<?php echo $row_img['imgname']; ?>">
        <h3><?php echo $row_title['title']; ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $row_description['des']; ?></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/<?php echo $row_img['imgname']; ?>">
        <h3><?php echo $row_title['title']; ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $row_description['des']; ?></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/<?php echo $row_img['imgname']; ?>">
        <h3><?php echo $row_title['title']; ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $row_description['des']; ?></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Since I use a simmilar code for the titles and descriptions, I have the same problem with them.

Comment: you have to loop through and display data.

Comment: I guess u got a lot of answers now :P

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php, http://www.php.net/while, http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php . There are many ways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_img = "SELECT imgname FROM img ORDER BY imgname";
$img = mysql_query($query_img, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
<ul>
    <?php
        while($row_img = mysql_fetch_assoc($img)) {
    ?>
        <li>
            <img src="images/<?php echo $row_img['imgname']; ?>">
            <h3><?php echo $row_title['title']; ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo $row_description['des']; ?></p>
        </li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>   

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a loop to iterate through the database resultset:

```
$img = mysql_query($query_img, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
while($row_img = mysql_fetch_assoc($img)) {
?>
    <li>
        <img src="images/<?php echo $row_img['imgname']; ?>">
        <h3><?php echo $row_title['title']; ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $row_description['des']; ?></p>
    </li>
<?php
}
```

Comment: will it automatically create as many li-elements as there are images in the database or do I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop through the results and include the `<li>` in that loop to get a list element per row returned from the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$img = mysql_query($query_img, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($img);
    foreach ($result as $row_img)
    {
    ?>
        <li>
            <img src="images/<?php echo $row_img['imgname']; ?>">
            <h3><?php echo $row_img['title']; ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo $row_img['des']; ?></p>
        </li>
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: thanks @kayra!  if I want to do this for multiply elements (both images, titles and descriptions), should I just copy the code (`foreach`) multiply times?

Comment: no. Your query will be something like this : "SELECT imgname,title,dec FROM img ORDER BY imgname". Therefore, it will get result as imgname,title and dec. The above code fetch everything for each row, and create <li> element for each row returned from table.

Comment: Then use another query to fetch title and description. THEN get $title_desc =  mysql_query($query_title_desc), result1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($$title_desc). Use foreach again, similar to img.

Comment: Lastly another way is create query to get result from 2 tables into 1 table and then use it to fetch together in one foreach loop.